# saving multiple records with transaction using yii :not using loop

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have something like this:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $a = new Tblcompany;
    $c = new Tblfunctioncontrol;

    $transaction= Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    try {
      if(isset($_POST['Tblcompany'])) {
        $a->attributes=$_POST['Tblcompany'];

        //}
        if($a->save()){
           //1st row       
           $c->company_code= $a->company_code;
           $c->usergroup_code= 'Admin';
           $c->function_code= 'M01-01-01';
           $c->description= 'Vehicle Setup';
           $c->hide_key= false;
           $c->add_key= true;
           $c->edit_key= true;
           $c->delete_key= true;
           $c->print_key= true;
```

Now, i also want to include another row for c

```
    //2nd row
           $c->company_code= $a->company_code;
           $c->function_code= 'M01-01-02';
           $c->description= 'Make Setup';
           $c->hide_key= FALSE;
           $c->add_key= TRUE;
           $c->edit_key= True;
           $c->delete_key= true;
           $c->print_key= true;
```

so, i want to include two row for $c here.need some explanation about how can i do it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is changing the entity which is referenced by `$c`. You are overwriting the values of your first row with the values of the second row. To create a second row just create a new object for your second row like this:

```
//2nd row
$c= new Tblfunctioncontrol;
$c->company_code= $a->company_code;
$c->function_code= 'M01-01-02';
$c->description= 'Make Setup';
$c->hide_key= FALSE;
$c->add_key= TRUE;
$c->edit_key= True;
$c->delete_key= true;
$c->print_key= true;
$c->save();
```

I don't see a call of `$c->save()` in your code. I guess you have just not posted it? Anyway you have to call it for your first and your second `$c`.

Comment: Thanx, got the idea now...worked also... and about the $c->save(); i didnt post it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use two arrays for entering this kind of requirement.

```
$arr1 = array("field_name" => "value","field_name" => "value");
$arr2 = array("field_name" => "value","field_name" => "value");
```

Now do something like this.

```
$model = new Model;

$model->attributes = $arr1;
$model->save();
$model = new Model;
$model->attributes = $arr2;
$model->save();
```

This will insert two values into the database without a for loop.

Comment: Thnx for the reply..got the idea now. Just need to create different objects.